# Xcode has no segue with identifier

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I have given a segue an identifier and the program will run and perform the segue and then crash with the error:

```
Thread 1: "Receiver (<Ralphy_s_PG_Leaderboard.ViewController: 0x7faa41309fd0>) 
has no segue with identifier 'homeSegue'"
```

this is under my `viewDidLoad`

```
let delay : Double = 2.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeSegue", sender: self)
}
```

so it does exactly what i want it to, it performs the segue after 2 seconds but then crashes with an error saying it cant find identifier.

Im confused because obviously it finds the segue because it performs the segue, but after it performs it, then it says it cant find it anymore.

Comment: are you sure that you have `homeSegue` identifier in one of your Storyboard's connections between viewcontrollers?

Comment: @stackich yes, i looked in the atributes section and its there and spelled correctly.